# Using json to import multidimensional data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to extract data relating to a specific gameweek from https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/

As you can see on the webpage that inside the 'events' array there are multiple objects (each gameweek is one object identified using the 'id' field).

I am trying to print the average score in gameweek 1.

I keep getting the "Undefined index: name" error. Could someone please help me figure out what i am doing wrong?

As you can see from the code i have tried the following:

I am trying to print the average score in gameweek 1.

```
$json2=file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap- 
static/");
$data2 = json_decode($json2, true);         
<?PHP
if($data2['events']['id']=1)
{
?>
<td><?PHP print $data2['events']['name']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP print $data2['events']['average_entry_score']; ?></td>
<?PHP
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things wrong with your code:

1. `<?PHP` inside PHP will give you a

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<',

2. `if($data2['events']['id']=1)`
   You are assigning a value, not comparing, this should be `if($data2['events']['id'] == 1)` - which would never trigger since `$data2['events']['id']` doesn't exist.

As you already stated `$data2['events']` is an array, so you can access its data via 
`$data2['events'][0]`, `$data2['events'][1]` etc.

The correct code to achieve what you want is:

```
<?php
$json2 = file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/");
$data2 = json_decode($json2, true);
?>
<td><?php print $data2['events'][0]['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php print $data2['events'][0]['average_entry_score']; ?></td>
```